# nginx upload progress return me always same size and recived

Tags: nginx, upload

I set my nginx static content domain like this:

```
#  static0.mywebsite.com static1.mywebsite.com static2.mywebsite.com static3.mywebsite.com
server {

        # upload limit
        # upload_limit_rate 10240;

        # request size limitation
        client_max_body_size 500m;
        client_body_buffer_size 64k;

        # document root
        root /home/mywebsite/myns-projects/mywebsite_com/static/public/;

        # index file
        index index.php;

        # server name
        server_name  static0.mywebsite.com;

        # rewrite rules
        rewrite "^/thumbnail/([A-Za-z0-9]{12})/(.*)/.*$" /index.php?request=thumbnail&unique=$1&parameters=$2 last;

        # set myns no cache
        set $myns_no_cache 1;
        if ($request_uri ~* "/thumbnail\/.*/") {
                set $myns_no_cache 0;
        }
        if ($request_uri ~* "/serve\/.*\.(jpg|gif|png|swf)/") {
                set $myns_no_cache 0;
        }

        if ($request_uri ~* "/serve\/.*\.(jpg|gif|png|swf)/") {
                set $myns_no_cache 0;
        }

        # upload
        location /upload {
                # proxy to upstream server
                proxy_pass http://static0.mywebsite.com;
                proxy_redirect default;

                # track uploads
                track_uploads uploadproxied 10s;

                # mvc rewrite
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?request=upload&$args;
        }

        # /
        location / {
                # expires
                expires max;

                # disable etag
                if_modified_since off;
                add_header 'Last-Modified' '';

                # mvc rewrite
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
        }

        # progress
        location /progress {
                # report uploads tracked in the 'proxied' zone
                report_uploads uploadproxied;
        }

        # php5-fpm
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9003;
                fastcgi_param myns_PATH /home/mywebsite/myns;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_cache_bypass $myns_no_cache;
                fastcgi_no_cache $myns_no_cache;
                fastcgi_cache mynsCACHE;
                fastcgi_cache_valid any 1h;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess and .user.ini files
        location ~ /\.[ht|user] {
                deny all;
        }

        # disable access log for better performace use at will
        # access_log /home/mywebsite/myns-projects/mywebsite_com/logs/static_access.log;
        access_log off;

        # logs
        error_log /home/mywebsite/myns-projects/mywebsite_com/logs/static_error.log;
}
```

After submitting response the jsonp return well but always `received` equal as `size`.

```
jQuery110109778769564112372_1428954161844({ "state" : "uploading", "received" : 2461040, "size" : 2461040 });
```

Nginx Version:

```
:~# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
built by gcc 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt=-Wl,-z,relro --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-file-aio --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/headers-more-nginx-module --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/naxsi/naxsi_src --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-auth-ldap --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-development-kit --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/ngx-fancyindex --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-push-stream-module --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-lua --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-upload-progress --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-syslog --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/ngx_http_pinba_module --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/ngx_pagespeed --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-x-rid-header --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/dotdeb-nginx/debian/modules/nginx-rtmp-module --with-ld-opt=-lossp-uuid
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue, and have created a pull request to restore the functionality of the nginx-upload-progress module with HTTP/2

https://github.com/masterzen/nginx-upload-progress-module/pull/57

With this fix, it should just work as it did before.

Answer (score 1):

> **track_uploads syntax**: track_uploads < zone_name> < timeout>
>
> **default**: n/a
>
> **context**: location
>
> This directive enables tracking uploads for the current location. Each
>   POST landing in this location will register the request in the
>   zone_name upload progress tracker. Since Nginx doesn't support yet RFC
>   1867 upload, the location must be a proxy_pass or fastcgi location.
>   The POST must have a query parameter called X-Progress-ID (or an HTTP
>   header of the same name) whose value is the unique identifier used to
>   get progress information. If the POST has no such information, the
>   upload will not be tracked. The tracked connections are kept at most
>   timeout seconds after they have been finished to be able to serve
>   unseful information to upload progress probes. WARNING: this directive
>   must be the last directive of the location. It must be in a proxy_pass
>   or fastcgi_pass location. Repeating the directive in a location will
>   results in segfaults.

So it seems that the track_uploads must be the last directive in the location block. Try switching your `track_uploads` and `try_files` directives in the `/upload` location.

Comment: First thank you for answer, but i try this : http://paste.ubuntu.com/10856930/ i have same problem. :(

Comment: Can you add the javascript code that makes the POST call to get the progress?

Comment: this is my entire client source code ... http://paste.ubuntu.com/10860359/ ... Thank

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment on previous answer

I have same problem

```
  location ^~ /upload/progress {
    upload_progress_json_output;
    report_uploads uploadtracker;
  }
  
  location / {
    uwsgi_pass  core;
    uwsgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO $scheme;
    include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 300;
    track_uploads uploadtracker 300s;
  }
```

but still received instantly equals size

javascript

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET", //post gives 405
    url: "/upload/progress/",
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Progress-ID", uuid);
        request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    },
    success: function(response) {
        try {
            switch(response.state) {
                case "uploading":
                    percent = parseInt(Math.floor((response.received / response.size)*100)); // always 100
```

P.S. I found that http2 breaks it, without http2 in listen everything works: https://github.com/masterzen/nginx-upload-progress-module/issues/45